# React native viewPager how to disable edge to edge

Tags: react-native, android-viewpager, viewpage

I'm using the react native viewPager from react native community : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager

And I would like to render something like the logo displayed on the main page :

[image]

But it looks like the childrens item of the viewPager must be stretch, So we can't see the part of the second children.

I tried to set a fixed width on the childrens component, but it doesn't works :

```
<ViewPager
            style={{
                height: 100
            }}
            pageMargin={5}
            initialPage={userPosition}
        >
            <View style={{width: 80, height: 100, borderColor: "green", borderWidth: 1}}/>
            <View style={{width: 80, height: 100, borderColor: "green", borderWidth: 1}}/>
            <View style={{width: 80, height: 100, borderColor: "green", borderWidth: 1}}/>
        </ViewPager>
```

There is a solution for this problem keeping that library ? Or should I take a look on a carousel library ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I switched to implement my own... try to look at a carousel solution.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager does not support this kind of feature. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/issues/37